# Why is my React hook (useNavigate) not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Previously, I used this.props.history.push, but now I'm attempting to transition to useNavigate. However, it doesn't seem to be working, and I'm uncertain about the reason behind this issue. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

this is the error:
Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

```
doLogin = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const { email, password } = this.state.loginData;
        const navigate = useNavigate(); 

        login({ email, password })
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(token => {
                localStorage.setItem('token', token);
                navigate('/deliveries');
            });
    }
```

Comment: You can only call hooks in the body of a function component. You are calling it in some random function, and it appears like it might be part of a class component. Are you trying to convert this component to a function component?